# Is it possible to upsert into a subcollection in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, mongodb-query, upsert

I am using a mongodb collection to store frequencies of words which are near other words like this:

```
{ word : "a", neighbours : [ { neighbour : "x", frequency : 1 }, { neighbour : "y", frequency : 2 } ] }
{ word : "b", neighbours : [ { neighbour : "y", frequency : 1 }, { neighbour : "z", frequency : 3 } ] }
```

Each document has a word and a list of subdocuments called neighbours (the nearby words). Each subdocument consists of a neighbour and a frequency of how often that neighbour is found to occur near the word.

What I want to do is to update the list of neighbours for a given word. The problem is that the update can be:

- A new neighbour, in which case a push has to be made
- Or an existing neighbour, in which case a increment to the frequency of the respective subdocument has to be made

What is the most efficient way to do this? At the moment I am first checking if the neighbour exists using a find, then do different updates depending on the result.

Comment: you cannot do this with your current schema. it's only possible if your subdocument was "x":1 where x is neighbour's name/id.  but that has other problems - querying may now be less flexible.

Comment: Wouldn't that limit what the keys can be? For example, they cannot start with a dollar sign.

Comment: ok, I don't know what neighbour represents - is x y their names?  Ids? like I said, that's not the schema for all use cases, but if you must have the ability to automatically create them if they don't exist that's a way to do it.